# How to Empty array in swift on logout

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Hi there guys I have movies array in MoviesViewController which has a tableView and where I display tableCells. And I have logout in SidebarMenuController which onTap goes to LogInController. When I hit logout I want to empty the movies array from MoviesViewController and go to LogInController. How to go about this?

Comment: arr = [ ] or arr = array() will work

Comment: Define movies array  globally. then you can access it  any place in your app.

Comment: @Arun I know how to empty array but I want to empty on logout button press from SidebarMenuController. Does array gets emptied automatically when I leave the MoviesViewController?

Comment: if you want to notify other vc from another vc , then you can use notificationcenter to post notification to that vc

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha where should I define this array. In AppDelegate or in MoviesViewController as public var movies =[Movie]() ?

Comment: I would send out a notification on tap. All observers can then do their own cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating an `Event` class that holds the array of movies. Then add an optional event property to `MoviesViewController` and observe setting it. On sign out, make the array empty, and set the event for the view controller. So the view controller would have something like:

```
var event: Event? {
    didSet {
        moviesArray = event?.movies
        tableView.reloadData()

        if moviesArray.isEmpty {
            presentLogin()
        }
    }
}
```

This could also be used to populate the array if getting from a service.